# problem with cloning git repository

Tags: git, public-key

I am trying to host a git repository. Googling around found [this tutorial](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) regarding hosting git repositories.  But things didn’t go well :(

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.
IP: 192.168.0.131
Openssh running on port 22

It was going good  till setting up gitosis-admin repo. Here is what I did.

I generated public key on this host linux machine and initialzed gitosis with that key.

```
ssh-keygen –t rsa.
sudo -H -u gituser gitosis-init < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then I tried to clone gitosis-admin repository on linux machine with different forms

```
git clone gituser@192.168.0.131:gitosis-admin.git 

git clone ssh://gituser@192.168.0.131:22/gitosis-admin.git
```

But getting ERROR:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005947/password-problem-with-git-clone-gitosishostgitosis-admin-git could help here

Comment: Note to moderator: git has nothing to do with superuser. It is a "software tools commonly used by programmers", which is 100% compliant with the StackOverflow FAQ.

Comment: Is your ssh key installed on the machine you are trying to clone from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not Gitosis itself, but that your SSH key gets rejected. This can be because it has not been authorized (is not in *gituser*’s `authorized_keys` file), because your SSH server is configured not to accept public keys, because your SSH key is weak or because you are not sending one at all.

Have a look at the logs of your SSH server to see whether (and why) your public key is rejected. On Ubuntu, the file should be located at `/var/log/auth.log`. Look for the word *publickey* and/or try cloning your repository to see what happens in the log file. You can use something like `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log` to watch new entries as they arrive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Now I am getting error 

fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Google indicates that this is a very common problem. tried all the options i could find with no luck :( 

Could you please direct me to right path?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This message means that at least the SSH part is working now. However, I’m no Gitosis user, therefore I cannot help you with that error. It would probably be best to ask another question about this.